# When does Autumn begin?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

I just realized that Autumn is coming up soon, but I wasn't sure when it arrives in Animal Crossing: New Leaf.

Does anyone know a specific date?

Answer (score 6):

[Autumn](http://animalcrossing.wikia.com/wiki/Autumn) starts the First of September in the Animal Crossing Series.

Answer (score 0):

The game is based on real time so it all works just like it does in the real world.

Comment: The game is not aware of the temperature, the amount of leaves on the trees, or your local calendar's definition of fall. It starts September 1 instead, for simplicity.